# function that is 1 when x=0 and 0 otherwise

Tags: functions, dirac-delta

I'm wondering if there is a function, or an easy way I can create a function from other elementary functions, such that $f(x)$ is $0$ whenever $x\neq0$ and $1$ whenever $x=0$. So, a function kind of like the loose/informal definition of the Dirac Delta function but with $\infty$ being $1$.
Thanks!

Comment: There it is, you have defined the function you're looking for!, ?

Comment: @GFauxPas. Maybe I wasn't clear, I need this function so I can use it in Wolfram (integrating it multiplied by other stuff etc.). Basically does this function have a name already, or can I make it from products,sum, etc. of other elementary functions.

Comment: Like in Wolfram if I need the Heaviside function I can use UnitStep[] and if I want the delta function I can use DiracDelta[]. I need a similar thing, or more reasonably, $f(x)= $ some combination of elementary functions.

Comment: Do you mean notation for a function specifically created for this function or a naturally occuring function that happens to have this property (or a function using only one case that has this propeerty)?

Comment: @asherdrummond the Kronecker Delta function is what I was looking for

Comment: Oh, okay. By the way, can you think of any one-case function that describes your title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have alluded to the Dirac Delta "function"; let me introduce you to the Kronecker Delta function:

$$\delta_{ab} := \begin{cases} 1; \ a = b\\ 0; \ a  \ne b \end{cases}$$

Where $a,b$ don't have to be numbers, but they can be.

So you can write:

$$\delta_{x,0} = \begin{cases} 1; \ x = 0\\ 0; \ x  \ne 0 \end{cases}$$

In WolframAlpha, you can write `kroneckerdelta(x,0)`

Edit: Another option is the Iverson Bracket.

$$[P(x)] := \begin{cases} 1; \ P(x) \\ 0; \ \neg P(x) \end{cases}$$

Where $P(x)$ is some prepositional function. So you can write:

$$[x = 0] = \begin{cases} 1;\ x = 0 \\ 0; \ x \ne 0 \end{cases}$$

In WolframAlpha, you can write `Boole(x=0)`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and actually I knew about this function but totally forgot!

Comment: I changed the title so any clumsy people like me who forget the Kronecker Delta function can find this easily