# A mathematical expression that gives 0 if variable is different from constant and 1 if variable same as constant

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Example,
∆ = any mathematical expression;
c = constant;
x = variable;

c∆x=1 (if c = x)
c∆x=0 (if c ≠ x)

am just asking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function that is 1 when x=0 and 0 otherwise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809058/function-that-is-1-when-x-0-and-0-otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) and write $[\Delta=c]$, though you should explain it the first time that you use it.

Comment: oh yeah....I just didn't realize the Kronecker delta

Comment: you can click on the grey tick if this answer has helped you

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$, which is often used in theoretical physics.

In your case, the function $\delta(x-c)$ has the property that it has value $1$ if $x=c$, and value $0$ if $x \neq c$.

For more details, you may wish to refer to this Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: If the dirac delta had value $1$ at zero, then its integral would just be $0$.